# WPML - ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE breaks my template

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, wpml

Using IF conditional with WPML should be easy but for some reason my template stops working as soon as i place following code in footer.php or everywhere else

```
<?php 
 if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en') {
     //english here
 } else {
     //other languages
 }
?>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I've just tested your code and can see absolutely no issue. I tested with the plugin both on and off with no issues. Can you post more of the footer code with the if statement. Also try putting  this in the header `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to show any errors that are occurring.

Comment: Sry for wasting your time, i found my 'bug' has nothing to do with WPML or WP. The code works fine, i just wasted about 5 hours of my life because of filezilla which started uploading corrupted files :(

Comment: Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
    <!-- english here -->
<?php elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?>
    <!-- spanish here -->
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- ======== Or ======= -->
<?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
    <!-- english here -->
<?php else: ?>
    <!-- spanish here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```